# Windows.Forms.Datagrid error markers

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, validation, datagrid

I'm looking for how to set the error markers (red ! marks) in a Windows.Forms.Datagrid.  After research I believe they appear after some validation routine, but how do I set these manually?  E.g. If each row goes to a stored procedure I'd like to place an error marker whenever the SP returns an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there I go answering my own question again.  All I did was:

```
dsOutput.Tables(0).Rows(2).RowError = "massive error"
```

for the dataset behind and it worked a treat.